# how to prevent my form submit after a result

Tags: jquery

I am working on captcha using jquery. i want to prevent form.php to submit when `data='false'`

Here is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
       val=$('#vercode').val();
       $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"verify-captcha.php",
           data:{'code':val},
           success:function(data){
               if(data=='false') {
                   $("#msg").html(data);
               }
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use return false statement:

```
if(data=='false'){
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent form submit use `event.preventDefault();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
       val=$('#vercode').val();
       $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"verify-captcha.php",
           data:{'code':val},
           success:function(data){
               if(data=='false') {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   $("#msg").html(data);
               }
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, and that's intended behavior, OP asks to prevent form submission only on captcha verification fail.

Comment: @TwiStar I would replace the click event listener with a submit event listener - To catch submitting the form by keyboard too.